# Error while configuring ADFS as Identity Provider using SAML Authentication

Tags: active-directory, saml-2.0, weblogic12c, adfs2.0

I am trying to configure ADFS 2.0 as Identity Provider with Oracle Weblogic Server as a service Provider using SAML 2.0 authentication.

When I try to hit the Load Balanacer URL I am redirected to the ADFS server but rather than seeing the login page I see the /adfs/ls/ directory contents.

I need the login page which will then redirect me to the service provider. Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The ADFS login page is by default located at:

> https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon

When authenticating against ADFS, the **SP** just needs to redirect the users to this URL (No need to pass SAML AuthnRequest). After succesfull authentication ADFS will redirect users back to the SP through a POST with the SAML AuthnResponse. This is what we call **Unsolicited Web SSO**.

Does this answer your question? Otherwise provide some little more information about the mentioned *Load Balanacer URL*.

Comment: Thanks,  the redirect takes me to https://adfs.domain.com/adfs/ls rather than the idpinitiatedsignon.aspx page. Is there a configuration change I need to do somewhere to make this happen? The login page most of the tutorials show is a blue microsoft azure like login page so I assumed its a separate entity.

Also, Could this have anything to do with the IIS configuration of Default web sites and their Authentication feature? 

P.S: The Load Balancer URL i was referring to is essentially the application URL, just that its accessed through a load balancer.

Comment: My ADFS knowledge is limited but my best guess would be that you wrongly configured your "Relying Party", e.g. forgot the specify SAML SSO as authentication ... Have a look at all the necessary steps listed at: https://guide.targetprocess.com/settings/how-to-set-up-single-sign-on-with-adfs.html . Best I can do I'm afraid ...

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that [Directory Browsing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx) is disabled in IIS for the Default Web Site, the "adfs" site and the "ls" site.  I'm not sure if this would interfere with the http handler ADFS users for requests to /adfs/ls/.